Soldering Iron - How long to heat the pad and component leads?
I'm fairly new to soldering and am curious as to how long it's supposed to take to heat the component contacts and copper pads on a PCB to get to solder-melting temperature.
I'm using a YIHUA 939D+ III EVO Digital Soldering Iron Station set for 350° Celsius which I bought new just a few months ago; the tip is clean and tinned, and it's placed so it's touching both the pad and the component, but it seems to take much too long to actually heat anything. Usually around 45-60 seconds if I'm lucky.
I'm really stumped here as to whether this is normal, I just suck at soldering, or the iron is defective. (I have a feeling it's that I suck, though.)

Dr Negative - Hi, Please [edit] the question and add: (a) What solder are you using? Preferably add a photo of the markings on the reel and say where you got it. (b) You've explained the issue when you're trying to solder a component to a board. How long does it take for just that solder to melt onto the soldering iron bit itself i.e. when tinning the bit? TY

What are the sizes of components you are trying to solder? A picture would help.

It may be that the tip of your soldering iron may have tin oxide on it which is not dissipating heat properly. This is what happens when tin of the solder stays too long and hot on the tip of the soldering iron while being in use. After a few minutes, it gets oxidized.
To remedy this, try to clean the tip of the oxide using a metal mesh which is with the soldering iron station. You can also use solder flux to remove excess solder off the tip of soldering iron.
You will face this problem over and over if you are applying solder to the tip of soldering iron and then soldering a part on a board because there would be some remaining solder on the tip of soldering iron.
Change your technique to the following:
Clean the tip of the soldering iron periodically. Apply the hot tip of soldering iron to the pin or a pad on a board.  Wait for 2-3 seconds until that pin or pad is heated and apply soldering wire to the pin or pad but not to the soldering iron.Heat on the pin or pad of a board would melt the solder wire and make soldering easy. This is the correct soldering technique. For soldering on delicate pins or pads which may melt, use your former method to apply solder directly to the soldering iron and solder to the pin or pad on the board. Use solder flux generously while soldering i.e apply solder flux to the pin or pad before it is heated with the soldering iron.

Maybe add that really old NASA movie on how to solder? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RXugDd0xik It's really old but the basics still apply. And who would question NASA?

There seem many tutorials like that. Whatever works should help.

Apply a liquid flux to the pad and part.
Make sure the iron is properly prepared, cleaned, and tinned. The trick is tinning the tip correctly so you have a blob of liquid solder on the tip. Plunge it so the blob makes contact with the pad and part. Then, immediately place the end of your solder into the liquid blob until you see the pad and part get wet. It should not take more than a few seconds.
Short article with pictures. Solder

"The trick is tinning the tip correctly so you have a blob of liquid solder on the tip" That's not really the correct way to solder, as all flux in the core will get vaporized that way. You can however nudge the solder with the tip when applying it to start the wetting. That link is of dubious quality, refer to the IPC standards instead.

It depends on the pad, naturally: the pad size and connections to large copper pour areas. Ground pins are usually harder to solder than signal pins for that reason: they are connected to copper pour which acts as heatsink.
However, it should not take more than a few seconds to heat the pad sufficiently with 350°C. What you describe is not normal, something is wrong. Likely causes:

Bad PCB layout. This is probably the most likely reason. If a pad layout lacks thermal relief in the form of multiple small traces connecting it to copper pour, but is instead directly attached to copper pour on the same layer or through a via, then it becomes impossible to solder the board proper. Hot plates or cranking the iron temperature up temporarily etc can be used to improve the situation, but the root cause is bad PCB design, which ought to be fixed.

Oxidation on the tip. Make sure the tip is wiped on a wet sponge/brass sponge before use. If there's oxidation or pollution on the tip that you can't get rid of that way, you could buy something called "tip cleaner" which can be used to dip the tip in.
"the tip is clean and tinned" is a weird thing to say: you should have no solder on the tip when heating the pad. You can use solder to clean it, but always wipe it off before soldering. Having solder on the tip usually won't do you any good since the flux core will be completely vaporized. It can however mess up the joint. In soldering utopia, the solder and the solder iron should never even touch each other.

Oxidation on the board.  In case the board is oxidated, apply external flux by for example using a flux pen. The rule of thumb is that you can never have too much flux. Make sure to store unsoldered PCBs in the vacuum packed plastic they arrived in to prevent oxidation.

Bad soldering iron. Some brands don't show the actual tip temperature but just an estimated guess. Avoid low budget Chinese brands - it is cheaper to buy an iron which actually works. Well-known mid-range brands like Hakko or Weller are good for hobbyists, if you don't want to fork out the cash for premium brands like Metcal or JBC.

Too small tip. For larger pads or through-hole work, use a flat "chisel" tip. The narrow, pointed tips should only be used for fine pitch and small components < 0805.

Bad solder. Make sure you don't buy solder (or anything else) from bad reputation scammer sites like Ebay, Aliexpress or Amazon. Buy from reputed electronics distribution sources like Digikey, Mouser, Farnell, RS etc.
Make sure you buy "rosin core no clean flux", meaning the solder has rosin flux inside and there is no need to clean the board after soldering. The exact alloy for RoHS solder isn't super important, you can do Sn/Ag/Cu or Sn/Cu. Supposedly Sn/Ag/Cu is better but I never noticed much difference. As a hobbyist you can also buy leaded solder (60/40) since you won't put the product on the market - leaded solder is much easier to work with. Buy 0.25mm for small SMD/fine pitch and 0.5 to 1.0mm for everything else.


